# Account not deleted after 24h with active session

Tags: support, deleted-users

I'm scheduled for delete my Stackoverflow account, but after 24h time is up and I was still logged in. Now page for 'account delete' says that 'account will by deleted 4 minutes ago' and time is increasing

Will by my account still deleted in later time. If so how long will I have to wait?

Need to delete account. Thanks for response.

Comment: @Camden I have canceled account deletion and renewed request

Comment: Give it another 16 hours so planet Earth can rotate into the right spot to provide daylight.

Answer (score 6):

From the [MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/158100):

> [...] The account will be scheduled for deletion.  During that time, you can cancel the deletion request by visiting your profile and clicking the cancel link in the banner at the top. Otherwise, it will be deleted after (approximately - see below) 24 hours.
>
> ### Why wasn't my account deleted immediately after the timer expiring?
>
> Accounts are not deleted immediately after the timer expires, but by a scheduled task that runs [once an hour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307244/why-i-cannot-delete-an-account-in-24-hours). Thus, you may see a notice that says "this account is scheduled for deletion [x] minutes ago", e.g. "5 minutes ago". This is intentional and by design; your account will be deleted within an hour of the timer expiring.

By cancelling your current deletion request and starting a new request, you have reset the timer and need to wait at least another 24 hours. And then take Hans's advice.